# On submit ajax request goes to another route instead of the one that is defined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have an ajax request that it should access a defined route, but it gets a response from another route instead. I checked for `Redirect` responses but there are none and it won't reach to the route defined by me. It is notable that the request accesses the route if one of the fields is already filled, for example: if the field X in my form has data which is loaded from database and try to update it, it reaches the action method, but if it has no data to be loaded and try to update it, it goes to another route. Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '{{ path("my_defined_route") }}',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,

      success: function (data, status) {
        //execute something
      },
      error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // display error
      }
    })
```

So to be more precise, when the form field has a value and I try to update it, it accesses 'my_defined_route' and returns a JSON response, but if the field has no value and try to update it, it reaches 'index_route' which returns a `Response` type and I get an error because it is an HTML response. Do you have any idea why does this occur? Because I also tried to debug step by step and cannot see where the problem is as the code already works if it has a value defined. Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the server code, not the client.

Comment: Use the DevTools Network tab to confirm that the request is being sent to the correct URL.

Comment: Use `bin/console debug:router` to confirm the order that the routes are matched.  Probably just a question of shifting the priority.